# How to get an external IP address without downloading any strings in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networking

I would like to get an external IP address without downloading any strings. Is it possible? Are there any libraries or methods I can use?

Comment: No. You *have* to ask an external server what your external IP is, because   there is nothing on your local machine that could tell you. The only other option is to store it as a configuration item for your application - i.e. have it known a priori.

Comment: (I'm assuming that by "external IP" you are referring to the IP address(es) you are using to connect to the internet)

Comment: I want to get the IP which service provider gives the router.

Comment: Then you'll need to ask an external server what your IP is (or possibly ask your router what it's external IP is if it exposes an API - either way you are "downloading strings"). Why would this be a problem? Do you have some restriction or something that prevents this?

Comment: Clients are having trouble when the connection is slow. Also, the domain I get the external IP may not be working in future, then I will need to change my code. I'm looking for a dynamic way.

Comment: Hmmm - what do you need the external IP for? Maybe there's a way around there?

Comment: I have them in database and check if a client at work or not while working.

Comment: Thanks for your effort though :)

Comment: Can you share some more details of your application and how it functions - it sounds like you want some sort of heartbeat monitor or similar, but I'm unclear on what your application is/does. Please **edit the question** to include this information.

Comment: (I know it must sound like I'm avoiding your question, but that's because what you are asking is not possible, but there is likely to be a better method of doing what you hope to acheive anyway).

Comment: I have a simple desktop notification application (winforms application) working with SignalR socket connection. Clients get notification contents according to their locations. So I have all the router IPs in database. I get their current external IP and compare with a list that I get from database and I get their locations. I know there are several ways to do it such as bluetooth beacon but I am currently using this method and clients have troubles with their connections sometimes.

Comment: Ok - how do you currently get the list of locations into your database though? Because that's the really relevant part...

Comment: Ultimately, I'm thinking that the "locations" can simply call a web-service on your SignalR server, and say "I am the Hospital", or "I am the Prison" repeatedly. Then your webservice will know the location and the IP, and so can put it into your database directly, rather than via, um, whatever mechanism you are currently using...

Comment: I get it with an SQL query, a stored procedure. I get them once while the application being launched.

Comment: Ok - then just do what I said - when your application launches get it to call a web-service to "register" it's location when it starts up. The application never actually needs to know what it's external IP is - only your SignalR service needs to know that.

Comment: That is true. When I need the location in the client-side I can get it from socket server later. Thanks for your helps. I will try it. But I will need a web-service.